# If G is Context free Language then L(G) = (sigma) * is decidable or undecidable?

Tags: context-free-grammar

If G is Context free Language then L(G) = (sigma) * is decidable or undecidable?
The source from where I got this question is telling that the answer is undecidable...but I think it is decidable
Because : since sigma * is infinite(correct me if I am wrong) and as infiniteness of context free languages is decidable so the above being a infinite context free Language I think it's decidable...

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your argument is that there are lots of infinite languages - all strings, strings of even length, palindromes, repeated strings, etc. It might be possible to tell that the language of a CFG is infinite without being able to tell exactly which infinite language it is. There are infinitely many languages which are identical to the language of all strings, except that they are missing a single string. Or two strings. Or three.

From Wikipedia:

> A reduction can be demonstrated to [the problem of whether a CFG generates all strings] from the well-known undecidable problem of determining whether a Turing machine accepts a particular input (the halting problem). The reduction uses the concept of a computation history, a string describing an entire computation of a Turing machine. A CFG can be constructed that generates all strings that are not accepting computation histories for a particular Turing machine on a particular input, and thus it will accept all strings only if the machine doesn't accept that input.